# Content div showing underneath fixed footer div

Tags: html, css

I am in the process of redesigning a launch page I have.  Currently I have been able to get my footer div to run along the bottom of the page and centered by having a fixed position, which I am using as the menu.  The only issue I am running into, however, is since this footer/menu div has a transparent background, if the content div above it contains more information than can fit on the page, the text is showing underneath the footer/menu div, making the menu unreadable.  Is there any way I can make the content div's height run only to the top of this fixed footer/menu, so the text from the content does not run underneath?

My CSS I have set up like so:

```
/*Global Settings*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Istok+Web);

* { margin: 0; outline: medium none; padding: 0; }

body { font: .9em 'Istok Web',sans-serif; background: url('../images/iQwallpaper.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; }

/*DIVS*/
div.header-outer { max-width: 100%; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px; }

div.menu-outer { width: 100%; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2); position: fixed; bottom: 0px; }

div.dashboard { max-width: 100%; max-height: 80%; overflow: auto; margin: 0 auto; }

div.left { float: left; }

div.right { float: right; }


/*MENU*/
#centeredmenu { float:left; width:100%; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }

#centeredmenu ul { clear:left; float:left; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; position:relative; left:50%; text-align:center; }

#centeredmenu ul li { display:block; float:left; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; position:relative; right:50%; }

#centeredmenu ul li a { display:block; margin:0; padding: 20px; color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; }

#centeredmenu ul li a:hover { background:#369; color:#fff; }

#centeredmenu ul li a.dashboard { background: rgba(255,51,51,0.3); }

#centeredmenu ul li a.dashboard:hover { background: rgba(255,51,51,0.6); }


img.icon { height: 200px; display: inline; margin: 25px 50px 25px 50px; }

.white { color: #f2f2f2; }
```

The HTML in the  tag is as follows:

```
<div class="header-outer">
<div class="left">
<h2 class="white">iQlaunch</h2>
</div>
<div class="right">
<p class="white">v 14.0.0 alpha</p>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="dashboard">
<p class="white">a bunch of text to get it to fill the page</p>
</div>

<div class="menu-outer">
<div id="centeredmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Customer Sites</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Support Tools</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Important Numbers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Helpfiles for Everyone</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Helpfiles for Support</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Internal Sites</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Scheduling</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Staff Phone Directory</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Training Presentations</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Mobile News Sites</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out how to do what I wanted.  I ended up creating two parent divs:

```
div.menu-outer { width: 100%; display:block; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; background: url('../images/iQwallpaper.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; /*background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);*/ }

div.menu-inner { background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2); }
```

The first parent div uses the same background settings as body, and then the second parent div inside the first one applies a transparent colour.  This makes it appear to be transparent from the body, but it really isnt. :)

Answer (score 0):

Which section has all your content?  I would suggest changing the "overflow" CSS setting to `hidden` or `scroll`.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp